# "Unbalanced" variation of rock-paper-scissors

Tags: recreational-mathematics, game-theory

This is based on a case from a question asking for the [optimal strategy for the original $11$ card version of the game](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1861105/weighted-war-game-of-mind-and-probability).

In short, I want to formulate this part of a case as a question on its own:

> Imagine a game like *rock-paper-scissors*, but you have a
>   **Swordsman**, a **Rouge**, and a **Wizard**. For simplicity lets label them with numbers $3$-$2$-$1$.
>
> Instead of each beating the other, they work in the following way in a
>   close up combat in broad daylight:
>
> - $3$ always **wins** against the $2$ - *rouge can't hide in the shadows during the day.*
> - $2$ always **wins** against the $1$ - *rouge is quicker than the wizard in close up combat.*
> - The battle between $1$ and $3$ has a $\frac{1}{3}$ chance of resulting in **win**, **lose** or **draw** for either. 
>   - *outcome
>     depends on the success of the spell the wizard attempts to use.*
> - Two equal numbers result in a **draw**. ($3,3$) ($2,2$) ($1,1$)
>
> Both players can send out any one of the three troop types, and the troop that wins gives a point to its master, both troops safely return home.

Now consider a set of $n$ games is being played. The overall winner is the one with the most points. Lets assume that a **draw must be resolved** by playing additional games until the winner is found.

If your opponent plays a troop at random, and you play a specific troop, you have the following chances to $\color{blue}{Win}$ / $\color{gray}{Draw}$ / $\color{red}{Lose}$ :

$$(3)\to \color{blue}{4}/\color{gray}{4}/\color{red}{1}$$

$$(2)\to \color{blue}{1}/\color{gray}{1}/\color{red}{1}$$

$$(1)\to \color{blue}{1}/\color{gray}{4}/\color{red}{4}$$

The optimal strategy would be to always play a $3$ - **Swordsman**, because you will either **win**, **draw** or have and equal chance to **win**, **lose** or **draw**.

But if both players follow the same "best method", the game **will always be a draw** forcing you into a endless loop of **draw** games. But we want the best method that will result in more wins for us than the opponent.

So to avoid this, we can add to our "best method" to play a $1$ if your opponent plays a $3$ for $k$-times in a row (Just after we are sure he won't play a $2$ to counter our $1$), and this pattern will result in $\frac{1}{3}$ chance of either **winning**,**losing** or **drawing** at the end.

But a **better method** would be to try to predict when the $1$ will be played and counter it with a $2$ to get a better than $1/3$ win rate (Not to be confused with a rate of scoring a "win" as a individual point). But if you fail of course, you give the advantage to the opponent.

---

> So my question is, what would be the best method and a **proof for it**?
>   The best method should have the best win rate against
>   any other method including the exact copy of itself. If my method is
>   the "best method", there are still some details to determine. Like how
>   large should $k$ be and how often should it change to avoid collision
>   between $1$ vs $1$, and a possible random play against a $2$?

Comment: Interesting question. I think the key thing to note here is that playing 3 every time seems to be an optimal strategy, assuming you don't know your opponent's strategy. There's no real counter to this either - playing a 3 will against this will draw, playing 2 will lose, and playing 1 will hypothetically draw as well, although their is greater variance. Playing 1 also subjects you to losing from a 2, so if your opponent can predict your moves to an extent you're playing sub-optimally. Therefore, I would argue that playing 3 always is the way to go.

Comment: @Matta If you define payoffs to each player from a win/draw/loss, and take your optimality criterion as maximising payoffs, you can appeal to von Neumann's [minimax theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimax_theorem). Otherwise, it's not clear to me how you can decide what the 'best' strategy is.